# Javascript function to insert information from API response

Tags: javascript, html, api

i have the following situation:

Api request structure:

```
http://www.api.com/?t=madrid&r=json
```

An api is giving me information with the following structure (its an json output if this helps):

API response 1:

```
{"Title":"madrid","Year":"2011","Location":"spain","time":"5days"}
```

API response 2:

```
{"Title":"buenos aires","Year":"2015","Location":"argentina","time":"2days"}
```

API response 3:

```
{"Title":"tokyo","Year":"2013","Location":"japan","Time":"7days"}
```

And i want to make an html javascript that can filter the title and location atributes to be shown under the following html structure:

```
<div id="travel">
  <h1 id="Title"> the title </h1>
  <p id="time"> time spent on the place </p>
</div>
```

The Year and Location attribute should be discarded.

How can i make that h1 show the information given in the Title section of the Api response and the time spent over the p tag? Can it be done with javascript? i cant use another language.

Comment: i dont know how to call the api to be shown in the html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can it be done with javascript?

Yes

> How can i make that h1 show the information given in the Title section of the Api response and the time spent over the p tag?

1) Use XMLHTTPRequest to get data

2) When data is retrived use a self-written function to format provided data (generate html-code)

3) Append the mentioned html-code wherever you need on the page

Comment: and how do i do this? pretty noob here

Comment: You can... google it. http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_callback - simple example of using `XMLHttpRequest` to retrieve data at url and insert it into the page. You will need to use some `forEach` implementation to go through your `JSON`  results.